# HTML5 Drag-And-Drop DataTransfer: Drag data sometimes in files sometimes in items

Tags: jquery, html, jsf, primefaces, drag-and-drop

I wrote up a script and html page to test out some drag-and-drop features with files from the file system dragged into the browser drop target I defined.

In this environment i was always able to access `event.dataTransfer.files`

However, I have since integrated this into a JSF servlet and suddenly the behavior is not as consistent.

I now see that in the dragover event the file is listed under `event.dataTransfer.items` but `event.dataTransfer.files` is empty. `DataTransferItem` object seems to reference the mimeType but not the data itself nor the filename like a `File` does. Yet on the drop event, `event.dataTransfer.files` contains the file.

Also, all of the getAs methods on `DataTransferItem` are returning null. I can work around a bit since I'm only really trying to figure out the file type at the dragover event, but I'd at least like to figure out these idiosyncratic behaviors.

I'm not sure what this change is caused by. The actual script hadn't changed and the related markup is all plain HTML and not JSF components. Why has the behavior changed?

Edit: It may be worth noting that the JSF implementation I am using is Primefaces and it contains a version of jQuery, which maybe older than the latest one I pulled from jQuery's site this week.

JS:

```
var CSVParser = (function($) {
  "use strict";

  var module = {

    /**
     * Inspects the file's name and mime-type to determine if it is a CSV file. Does not inspect
     * contents.
     * supports any mime type that contains csv, is comma-separated-values, or is application/vnd.ms-excel
     * @param file - javascript file
     */
    isCSV: function(file) {
      if(file) {
        var mimeType = file.type;
        var name = file.name || ".csv";  //Deal with possibly getting a DataTransferItem instead of File object. Just assume .csv

        var matchStandardMime = mimeType.match(/.*\/csv.*/) !== null || mimeType.match(/comma-separated-values/) !== null;
        var matchExcelMime = mimeType.match(/application\/vnd.ms-excel/) !== null;
        matchExcelMime = matchExcelMime && name.match(/.*\.csv/) !== null;

        return matchStandardMime || matchExcelMime;
      }
    }
  };

  return module;

}(jQuery));

(function($){

  /* Deal with drop-files */

  function getDropbox() {
    return $('.csvDropTarget');
  }

  function getEventFiles(e) {
    var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files || [];  //jQuery seems to wrap the original event
    var items = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items || [];  //jQuery seems to wrap the original event
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';

    if(files.length > 0) {
        return files;
    } else if (items.length > 0) {
        return items;
    }

    return files;
  }

  function onDragEnter(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  function onDragOver(e) {
    var files = getEventFiles(e);
    var validDrop = false;

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      if(files[i] && CSVParser.isCSV(files[i])) {
        validDrop = true;
      } else {
        validDrop = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  function onDragLeave(e) { 
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  function onDrop(e) {
    var files = getEventFiles(e);
    var file = null;

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    // Loop through list of files user dropped.
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      file = files[i];
      console.log("File type: " + file.type);

      console.log("Is CSV: " + CSVParser.isCSV(file));
    }
  }

  /* Register events and determine functionality */

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var dropbox = getDropbox();

    dropbox.bind("dragenter", onDragEnter);
    dropbox.bind("dragover", onDragOver);
    dropbox.bind("dragleave", onDragLeave);
    dropbox.bind("drop", onDrop);
  });

}(jQuery));
```

HTML snippet:

```
<div class="csvDropTarget mainDropTarget">
  <span class="dragDropText">${resourceBundle.csv_drag_prompt}</span>
  <span class="validDropText hidden">${resourceBundle.csv_valid_drag}</span>
  <span class="invalidDropText hidden">${resourceBundle.csv_invalid_drag}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not directly related, but http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Debugging-the-Filesystem-API points out there is different behavior between file:// and other protocols. In my case I was running the original html from file while the JSF deployment is over http.